# jquery datepicker how to disable all past dates and until future specific date

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I'm using jquery datepicker and my problem is that i want to disable all past dates and up to future date 13 march 2016.After 13 march 2016 user can select date.i tried with following

```
$(function() {
    $( "#pickup_date" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0,
      beforeShowDay: function(date) { return [date.getDay() == 3, ""];}

    });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use `minDate` as **@JiaJain** stated WITHOUT a `maxDate`. setting `maxDate` to `new Date` would not allow user to enter a future date more than today.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#pickup_date" ).datepicker({ 
       minDate: new Date(2016, 2, 14)
    });
 });
```

Using `14` will set the minimum date to 14th of March, *After 13 march 2016*.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`minDate`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) option, like this.

```
$("#pickup_date").datepicker({ minDate: new Date(2016, 2, 13) });
```

A snippet from the docs:

> The minimum selectable date. When set to `null`, there is no minimum.

You were close, just that setting `minDate` to `0` does not help at all.

Comment: Whoops, forgot about it. Updated to reflect March as `2`. Thanks!

Comment: But how user can select future date that mean if i want to book on future  ?

Comment: What will be the output  
$( "#pickup_date" ).datepicker({ maxDate: new Date(2016, 1, 22), minDate: new Date(2016, 1, 24)});

Comment: @AvijitNanda you should be setting `minDate` to be earlier than (or the same as) the `maxDate`.